# what is getPagerHtml()?

Tags: widgets

I'm seeing this in a widget and would like to know what it does.  I'm unsure as to where to look for documentation in regards to issues like this as well, any helpful pointers / ways to streamline search are appreciated.

In the expressed widget on the page i'm seeing the page number, however, i'd like to modify this code and would like to know where this function is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to find the method definition is a grep or awk search in your filesystem / IDE search for

```
n getPagerHtml(
```

This will match

```
[private|protected|public] function getPagerHtml(
```

while avoiding the matching of uses of `getPagerHtml` in the code itself.

Because Magento is extensible, the best folder in which to search recursively is *`./app/code`*, as this will contain all class definitions from the core, third-party vendors, and local modifications. If the result turns up nothing, you can also try a search in *`./lib`*.

If you do not find a method definition, it should be noted that `get*()` and `set*()` methods in Magento may not be explicitly declared, due to the `__call()` implementation in [`Varien_Object`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/lib/Varien/Object.php#L622) (along with `has*()` and `uns*()` methods).

In your case, you are probably looking for [`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_New::getPagerHtml()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Widget/New.php#L183).

Answer (score 1):

Actully you have not specified what would you like to do 
but if you wanna find where this function is defined and declare 
please see the below

```
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml
```

That is for the product listing ....
That same for sidebar, new listing , order history etc 
all types of pager comes from associated block class..

Comment: "seeing this in a widget"